# float32 placeholder in tensorflow keep on returning 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

while trying to run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b:4.5}))
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1,3], b: [2, 4]}))
```

i keep on getting the following results:
0.0
[ 0.  0.].
Is anyone else faced those same issues?

while changing the placeholders to int32 the results started to make sense...

I'm using: 
Tensorflow  1.0.1
python 3.5.2+ and also tried that on python 2.7.12+ and got the same results.

this is the full output

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally

W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 

name: TITAN X (Pascal)

major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.531

pciBusID 0000:02:00.0

Total memory: 11.90GiB

Free memory: 11.60GiB

W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x33a4610

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 1 with properties: 

name: GeForce GT 740

major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.0715

pciBusID 0000:03:00.0

Total memory: 1.95GiB

Free memory: 1.66GiB

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 1

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:777] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 0

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 1 

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y N

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 1:   N Y 

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0)

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:962] Ignoring gpu device (device: 1, name: GeForce GT 740, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0) with Cuda multiprocessor count: 2. The minimum required count is 3. You can adjust this requirement with the env var TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT.

7.0

[ 7.  0.]
```

Comment: I see you got the correct result for your first query, tried it on my environment and got the both results correctly. Running python 3.5 and tf 1.0.

Comment: Works fine for me, too (Python 3.5.2, tf 0.12)

Comment: Also working for me. Python 2.7 and TensorFlow 1.0. What happens if you run on a CPU-only version of TensorFlow? It could be an issue with your GPU setup / CUDA drivers.

Comment: Also as a side note, I had to add in `sess = tf.InteractiveSession()` in order to get your code to run.

Comment: you are correct, when i run on the CPU its runs smoothly ...
looks like a GPU issue... i have Titan X Pascal... does it requires special handling ? because once i run it on GeForce GTX TITAN it runs smoothly with the same code

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14177 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070348/getting-different-value-with-placeholder-over-cpu-gpu