# Getting different value with placeholder over CPU/GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I run at below code, I think I am getting the wrong results.
**OVER GPU**

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b: 4.5}))
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1, 3], b: [2, 4]}))
```

> **Output:**
>   3.0
>   [ 1. 3.]

I think the true result should be;
**7.5**
**[ 3.  7.]**

**OVER CPU**

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    adder_node = a + b
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b: 4.5}))
print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1, 3], b: [2, 4]}))
```

> **Output:**
>   7.5
>   [ 1. 3.]

**Tensorflow Version:**
'1.3.0'
**Python Version:**
Python 2.7.12

I am getting different results when I run over CPU and GPU. 
Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I run the same code and get correct result. could not produce your output. are you sure is the code producing that output? My tensorflow and python  versions are the same as yours.

Comment: @Mitiku Yes i am sure , i also ve tried with open new terminal and .py folder. Thank you for your interest

Comment: Works as expected on my machine too, both CPU and GPU. Did you try to reinstall tensorflow?

Comment: @Maxim .I think if i reinstall tensorflow, the problem will be solved but i am trying to understand the reason of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code and I got the true result. 
I am also using 
Tensorflow Version:
'1.3.0'
Python Version:
Python 2.7.12

[Screenshot of the code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf04i.png)

Comment: Can you say your tensorflow version and python release?

Comment: I have already mentioned it in the answer, Tensorflow Version: '1.3.0' Python Version: Python 2.7.12